# set styling to div which contain TextInput field

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm new to react and material ui. I'm using material ui version "1.0.0-beta.17" and react 15.6.2. Also has styled-components 2.0.0 and styled-components-breakpoint 1.0.1.

I have two TextInput fields in a div element.

```
const mycomponent = ({props}) => {
  <div>

    <SomeComponent />
    <div>
       <TextInput id="testId1" />
       <TextInput id="testId2" />
    </div>

  </div>
}
```

Now when it render, it adds additional parent div to each input fields
Like this,

```
<div>
    <div class="field--testId1">
       <div class="FormItem__ElementWrapper-s14tem39-3 bgVlIQ">
           <input id="testId1">
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field--testId2">
       <div class="FormItem__ElementWrapper-s14tem39-3 bgVlIQ">
           <input id="testId2">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now how can I target to the div to apply styles with class name field--testId1, field--testId2. 
Here classname are generated by default material ui,
for example

```
.field--testId2{
  width: "48%",
  float: "left"
}
.field--testId2{
  width: "48%",
  float: "left"
}
```

I'm learning react and material ui so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is `TextInput` your custom component based on `Input` from Material UI?

Comment: I use this: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/

Comment: Ok. Do you want to change the wrapper around input with `field--testId1` or the input itself?

Comment: @Mirakurun It is custom component.

Comment: The solution which ronen provided worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to override an existing class, you can add a styled-component wrapper instead of the wrapping div and override the child classes:

```
 const TextInputWrapper = styled.div`
     .field--testId2 {
          // your custom styling
     }
 `
<TextInputWrapper>
   <TextInput id="testId1" />
   <TextInput id="testId2" />
</TextInputWrapper>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target `div` which has `input`, than you can follow these steps

- Add a class to parent div, lets say `wrapper`
- Target the closest div using `>` `css selector`

```css
.wrapper > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="field--testId1">
       <div class="FormItem__ElementWrapper-s14tem39-3 bgVlIQ">
           <input id="testId1">
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field--testId2">
       <div class="FormItem__ElementWrapper-s14tem39-3 bgVlIQ">
           <input id="testId2">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You give class directly to your textfield component and you can add your custom styles.

```
  <TextInput className="your-class" id="testId1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [@material-ui/styles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#material-ui-styles) to extend your component's styles. Take a like at this answer, it's similar to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67512965/8950820. Here is and example:

You should use `@material-ui/styles` to extend your Text Fields styles like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  textField: {
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    padding: '0px 30px',
    // Other styles here...
  },
});

export default function MyComponent() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div>
            <TextField 
                size="large"
                variant="outlined"
                label="A text field title"
                className={classes.textField}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Learn more about the documentation at this link: [@material-ui.com/styles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#material-ui-styles)

Comment: Hi there. Link based answers can be made comments. If you rather wish it be an answer. Consider including a code snippet for better reach next time.

Comment: I just registered and my profile does not allow me to comment on the post of the author of the question. This is the reason why I put the link in response.