# Material-UI Class names keep changing every time I hit refresh

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Currently I'm working with Text Fields in Material-UI and I am wanting to shrink them down.
Here is an example of the class name:

.eKdARe.header .input-container input

Here is an example after I input changes in my file of what happens to class name after I hit refresh:

.hrLLok.header .input-container input

I just want to keep the one class name so that I can make actual changes to my input fields.

Comment: This is expected. Instead of targeting hashed class names, you should be using the [styles API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#why-use-material-uis-styling-solution) to override components' stylings.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@material-ui/styles` to extend your Text Fields styles like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  button: {
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
    // Other styles here...
  },
});

export default function MyComponent() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div>
            <Button className={classes.button}>My styled boutton</Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Learn more about the documentation at this link: [@material-ui.com/styles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#material-ui-styles)

Comment: worth pointing out that it's redundant to add this package if one is using MUI components, as it is a dep of the core package

Answer (score 0):

**My Problem is solved with the installation of**

**with npm**

```
npm install @mui/styles
```

**with yarn**

```
yarn add @mui/styles
```

> use **@mui/styles** instead of **@material-ui/core** problem solved in my case.

you should be using the basic [styles API](https://mui.com/styles/basics/) to override components' stylings.